# VBA Access Error 3134 Syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to fix my first INSERT INTO statement for school. Here is the string for the CurrentDb.Execute strSQL

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO [Procedure] (UserName, Date, StartTime, EndTime, Semester, FacilityID, Doctor, CaseID, ServiceID, RoleName, Trainer, Comment, Updated_By, Updated_Datetime) VALUES ('username', '12/04/2018', '01:30 PM', '02:00 PM', 'Fall', '4', 'Dr. Who', 'Cataract Extraction with Stent For Glaucoma', '4', 'OS', 'Trainer', 'Comment', 'username', '4/23/2018 7:51:00 PM');"
```

Procedure Field Names:

```
UserName, Date, StartTime, EndTime, Semester, FacilityID, Doctor, CaseID, ServiceID, RoleName, Trainer, Comment, Updated_By, Updated_Datetime
```

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you!!
-Tyler M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have a field in your table that is named the same as reserved word (built in function)

```
Date
```

Rename that field in your table, to something better like

```
DateOfProcedure
```

and your query will work (after editing your query string also of course)

In Access Debug window (Ctrl + G) you can run

```
? AccessError(3134)
```

and it will return

```
Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
```

While you are there in the debug window type

```
? date
```

There is the reserved word you are trying to use for a field name in the table, causing the SQL query to fail.

Also two other tips (optional)

If any of those ID fields are numbers, you don't have to enclose the Value in single quotes (can have no quotes, so long as the whole query string is enclosed in double quotes)

And for date/time fields, you can use # symbol instead of single quotes to enclose a date/time value

Comment: Thank you for all the information! It works great now! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try putting square brackets around your field names

I know for sure that **[Date] is a reserved word** in MS-Access - so that one should be wrapped as in

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO [Procedure] (UserName, [Date],....
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, date/time fields must be passed proper values, and no quotes around numeric values:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO [Procedure] (UserName, [Date], StartTime, EndTime, Semester, FacilityID, Doctor, CaseID, ServiceID, RoleName, Trainer, Comment, Updated_By, Updated_Datetime) VALUES ('username', #12/04/2018#, #01:30 PM#, #02:00 PM#, 'Fall', 4, 'Dr. Who', 'Cataract Extraction with Stent For Glaucoma', 4, 'OS', 'Trainer', 'Comment', 'username', Now());"
```